# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'author' (Discord Bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

The following is my code for an Amazon web scrapper. But I am getting the Client object has no attribute 'author' error. It specifically says File
"/Users/kailash/Documents/devkai/Amazon Scrapper/bot.py", line 13, in on_message
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'author'

On line 13, there is just a blank link though.

```
import discord
from amazon import search

TOKEN = 'hidden'
CHANNEL_ID = 'hidden'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:   #line 11
        return 
#line 13
    if message.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID:
        return

    if message.content.split(' ')[0] == '!amazon':
        try:
            query = message.content.replace('!amazon ', '')

            item = search(query)

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=item['title'],
                url='https://www.amazon.co.uk/' + item['url']
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url=item['img']
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name='Price',
                value=item['price']
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name='Rating',
                value=item['rating']
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name='Number of Ratings',
                value=item['number_of_ratings']
            )
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            response = 'An error occurred with your request.'
            await message.channel.send(response)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I tired changing the version of my discordpy to 1.0.1, but that did not help. still AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'author'. Please help

What my terminal says:

/usr/local/bin/python "/Users/kailash/Documents/devkai/Amazon Scrapper/bot.py"
2022-11-16 21:42:22 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
is not resumed until the WebSocket connection is terminated.
File "/Users/kailash/Documents/devkai/Amazon Scrapper/bot.py", line 13, in on_message
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'author'

Comment: I see that at the top of your code where the error is, you are saying that the error returns that client has no attribute user, but when describing the error you are saying it has no attribute author. Which one is it?

Comment: @SamShields No, I am simply pointing out the line numbers.  The error that I am getting is a no attribute author

Answer (score 0):

I think your attribute error is being caused by your client definition. You define `client` as `discord.Client` however, this is usually done by defining client like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix') # you can add other stuff here too but this is just the basics
```

Hope this helps